# Jacobian matrix in ode15s

Tags: matlab

I was wondering if there is possible to see the evaluated Jacobian (the matrix with numerical values) for each iteration in the integration process of [`ode15s`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode15s.html), say, as in Debugging mode.

I tried going directly to `odenumjac.m` file (at which numerically calculates the Jacobian), and putting a break point at the end of the function and it worked for t = 0; however, I am interested in looking at the values for t>0.

Comment: How did you [specify your Jacobian](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/odeset.html#zmw57dd0e478609)? Are you sure that your Jacobian isn't constant? If it's constant then that's why you'd only see output one time. You should look where `odenumjac` is called in the `ode15s` code.

Comment: Thanks!! I will take a look at the ode15s.m file. On the other hand, I didn't specify the Jacobian because it is too complex for my system, so I let Matlab do the work for me.